# c++ is it safe to read a map that may be written at the same time?

Tags: c++, dictionary, thread-safety

I have two thread, thread 1 may add or delete to a map

```
//t1
std::map<int, int> my_map;
my_map[9] = 9;
```

And thread2 check if a certain key exists in the map,

```
//t2
void check_and_act() {
    if(my_map.find(9)==my_map.end()) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

`check_and_act` in `t2` will be called repeatedly, so I do not care if operation in `t1` is performed earlier or later than check done in `t2`, is there going to be any undefined behavoir in this case?

Comment: C++ standard containers aren't thread safe, period.

Comment: If you don't add your own synchronization, there is no guarantee that `my_map.find(9) == my_map.end()` won't change between when you evaluate it and when you `//do something`.